# sharepoint SP2007 SQLQuery

Tags: sharepoint

I have to query a Sharepoint List, but displaying data by creating the view has not fulfilled my requirements.

I have gone to WSS_Content of my Sharepoint Database and I'm able to query against the List Data.

I have used only select statements to get the data. I am very much sure that I should not create any stored procedures on the WSS_Content database.

I want to create stored procedure and call that stored procedure for **my** SSRS. Where should I store that stored procedure?

Comment: Direct access to the SharePoint content databases is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, As per microsoft standards developers are not allowed to modify/ the content db directly.

First let me know what data you are looking for is it from a single list or multiple lists.
If it is multiple list try to use SPSiteDataQuery and fetch the data into an object/collection then implement your query. If it is single list it would be much easier to use caml query and on top of that make use of any filters.